# Android push c2dm Not working with a 200 ok reponse

Tags: android, push, response, android-c2dm

I've been trying to send a push message from my java EE web app, to my Android phone.

I've followed and read a lot of tutorial (like this one http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html)

I successfully get my registration_id on my Android Phone.
Then I sent a POST request witch sent me a "200 ok" response !

But I can't get nothing on my BroadcastReceiver...

The "200 OK" response mean that the message as been send ? What can i do ?

Thanks guys ;)

Comment: Probably mistakes in the manifest, wrong message receiver intent-filters maybe?

Comment: Yep, please share your manifest.xml so we can try to help you...

Comment: Please, make sure your android device has Google account and Market Sync.

Comment: @ANUP If the device does not have the Market and Google Account would the Android App receive a registration_id?

Comment: Please share the posting code too. Did you get the server auth code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little feedback about this issue :
This was a problem from my local network... All the port were closed.

It tried with 3G and it works...

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to check here.

1. Did you declare your receiver for messages in the manifest? this is a seperate receiver for when the application receives messages. Ensure that the package name also matches yours. It should look similar too:

   ```
    <receiver
       android:name=".C2DMMessageReceiver"
       android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" >
           </action>

           <category android:name="jakebuller.liveapp" />
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```
2. You need to make sure you created another class with a matching name to the name of the receiver declared in the manifest as seen above. this class is much like the registration receiver.

I had the same issue a few days ago and it turned out to be the receiver not being declared in the manifest properly so just be sure to triple check that. hope this helps!